# How to Enable Java Persistence 2.0 for Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, persistence, weblogic

I am using eclipse with weblogic server. In order to add the project to the weblogic server, it needs to support Java Persistance 2.0, however when trying to install it, I keep getting this message

Error Enabling Java Persistence 2.0 in Weblogic Server installation

I tried to follow the Oracle documents to solve this but they make no sense since I'm pretty novice with Weblogic.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#CIHDJHHI

Please help! I understand the second part of the manual but I have no idea how to configure this Top Link stuff. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have enabled JPA 2.0 on a Unix-based system using a variation on the 'Installing Manually' steps in the Oracle doc you referenced. The key is to add the two JPA jars at the beginning of the classpath. In my case, we wanted JPA 2.0 support for a single managed server in the domain, so I added the following hack at the beginning of the setDomainEnv.sh script:

```
if [ "${SERVER_NAME}" = "TEST_Server1" ] ; then
    JPA20="path/modules/javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}path/modules/com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar"
    if [ "${PRE_CLASSPATH}" != "" ] ; then
            PRE_CLASSPATH="${JPA20}${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}"
            export PRE_CLASSPATH
    else
            PRE_CLASSPATH="${JPA20}"
            export PRE_CLASSPATH
    fi
fi
```

Adjust the `TEST_Server1` name (or just remove the if) and `path`
references to align with your environment.

Comment: Thanks I get the idea, now I just have to convert that in the windows-based system. Thanks!

Comment: @hthomos - did you ever get it working for your windows environment?  Can you share what you came up with?

Comment: @Drew So the weirdest thing happened. Instead of trying to enable it from Servers->Add Servers I just went to Preference->Servers->Weblogic and clicked on install JPA 2.0 and it works from there. It was all Interface.

Answer (score 4):

Probably, the WebLogic Server Monitor was locking the weblogic.jar, so you couldn't upgrade the server.

I had the same issue and solved it by switching to a new workspace. There, I could add the server again and upgrade it, without being disturbed by the WebLogic Server Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the 'Smart Update' utility that was located in: start->program files->Oracle WebLogic->Smart Update (Windows server, obviously)

The hardest part was locating the Oracle patch number for JPA 2 for my version of WebLogic (10.3.6).

For those of you in the same boat this is the info for the patch for version 10.3.6:

Smart Update patch 7BWI for WebLogic Server 10.3.6

## Content:

This patch contains Smart Update patch 7BWI for WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0

## Description:

Enable JPA2.0 support on Weblogic server.

## Patch Installation Instructions:

- copy content of this zip file with the exception of README file to your SmartUpdate cache directory (MW_HOME/utils/bsu/cache_dir by default)
- apply patch using Smart Update utility

I am not sure how to attach files to this post or I would just include the patch.  Message me if you want me to email a copy to you.