# Spring 4 + hibernate & jpa 2.1 on weblogic 10.3.5

Tags: jpa, weblogic

Will I be able to run Hibernate with JPA 2.1 on weblogic 10.3.5.

I have specified the below lines in weblogic-application.xml and packaged the jpa 2.1 API jar in the EAR along with other jars.

`<wls:prefer-application-packages>
       <wls:package-name>javax.persistence</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>`

Some how weblogic recognizes META-INF/persistence.xml and tries to automatically create persistence unit using Eclipse Link during application deployment/startup. This is where the weblogic classloader (parent of application class loader) is trying to load the persistence unit but failing with below exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory is not visible from class loader

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled JPA 2.1 on your Weblogic Instalation ?

If you refer to :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1309

and

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/EJBAD/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1309

you will note that:

"Support for JPA 2.1 in WebLogic Server is provided as a patch because JPA 2.1 is part of the Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) 7. Therefore, enabling JPA 2.1 support in the current release results in WebLogic Server not meeting all Java EE 6 compatibility requirements. To maintain Java EE 6 compatibility, the files required for JPA 2.1 support are not enabled by default, although they are included in a standard WebLogic Server installation."

Have a look @

[How to Enable Java Persistence 2.0 for Weblogic 10.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413068/how-to-enable-java-persistence-2-0-for-weblogic-10-3-6)

and

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1309

Comment: Thank you for the information. I couldn't update it at weblogic level since we have other applications that are still using JPA 1.0 running on the same server. So I am trying to see if I can load JPA 2.1 API at application level and not disturb the weblogic so that other applications keep running.

Comment: Aha OK. But still that should not stop you . I would go and create a new domain using the console and then go ahead and edits it's startWeblogic.cmd as per the instructions to enable JPA 2.1. That way one domain can use the JPA 1.0 and the newer code can be deployed to the JPA 2.1 enabled domain..

Comment: Thank you @mkane. In that case I have to work with our Weblogic admins to have this setup which I am trying to avoid so that all our weblogic installations are consistent (there are tons of them). Basically I am trying to use weblogic like a servlet container instead of like an application server for now. Our organization have plans to eventually move to a servlet container instead of application servers for new developments.